# How to play background music online in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8

In my application, I use UI MediaElement. But when i click the Windows key, the music stops.

I tried using:

```
MediaControl.PlayPressed += MediaControl_PlayPressed;
        MediaControl.PausePressed += MediaControl_PausePressed;
        MediaControl.PlayPauseTogglePressed += MediaControl_PlayPauseTogglePressed;
        MediaControl.StopPressed += MediaControl_StopPressed;
```

I set source MediaElement:

```
media.Source = new Uri("http://stream-hq.mp3.zdn.vn/fsgggsfdlwjglwjAAAAA/2a3f830202ea6d29bc7c5a5146401566/4ff5620a/2011/12/27/a/4/a4fcc199a184a93cfeb0fe35642c53bf.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Please help me!

Comment: There's [a whitepaper by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh770517) on exactly that topic.

Answer (score 10):

For a Metro/WinRT app to play audio in background, the app needs the following:

1. A [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242926.aspx) control that:

   1. Is in a XAML page.
   2. The [AudioCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.audiocategory.aspx) property set to [BackgroundCapableMedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.audiocategory.aspx) (as in Armando's answer). There are other values for games or communication systems as needed. See the [Audio Playback in a Metro Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh770517) for information on what the different options mean.
2. Use the [MediaControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol%28v=win.10%29.aspx) object to capture at least the following. Other events and properties can be handled if desired but the following are required for background playback to function.

   1. [PlayPressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol.playpressed.aspx)
   2. [StopPressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol.stoppressed.aspx)
   3. [PlayPauseTogglePressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol.playpausetogglepressed.aspx)
   4. [PausePressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol.pausepressed.aspx)
3. Add audio to the list of support background tasks in the applications manifest. The manifest is usually called `Package.appxmanifest`. Select it in the Solution Explorer, go to the Declarations tab and check "Audio" as shown:

[image]

See the [Transport Controls Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh833781) for more info about capturing hardware buttons (e.g. play/pause on the keyboard) and the [quickstart guide for creating a media player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh986967.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my first answer. Make sure you set `AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia"` in your XAML like this:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="backgroundMusic" 
              AutoPlay="True" 
              AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" 
              Source="mms://betafm.santafe-conicet.gov.ar:1175">
</MediaElement>
```

Hope it helps!