# Background audio not working in windows 8 store / metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I've tried setting background audio through both a mediaElement in XAML

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MyAudio" Source="Assets/Sound.mp3" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoPlay="False" />
```

And programmatically

```
async void setUpAudio()
{
    var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
    var installedLocation = package.InstalledLocation;
    var storageFile = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\Sound.mp3");
    if (storageFile != null)
    {
        var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        _soundEffect = new MediaElement();
        _soundEffect.AudioCategory = AudioCategory.BackgroundCapableMedia;
        _soundEffect.AutoPlay = false;
        _soundEffect.SetSource(stream, storageFile.ContentType);
    }
}

// and later...
_soundEffect.Play();
```

But neither works for me. As soon as I minimise the app the music fades out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[akton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1634846/akton) replied to a similar question with [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341772/how-to-play-background-music-online-in-windows-8)

It wasn't easy to find initially as it doesn't use 'audio' in the title and I wasn't playing music. It's an excellent, comprehensive answer, the likes of which I love to see on StackExchange. It also mentions a few things other answers to similar questions had failed to point out. In brief

- You need to handle the **MediaControl** events `PlayPressed`, `PausePressed`, `PlayPausedTogglePressed` and `StopPressed`, *even if you have no buttons*. EDIT: these events are required by Windows 8 app certification, make sure they actually work.
- Add audio to the list of support background tasks in the applications manifest [see aktons answer for more detail]

However, in implementing this solution I did come across what I can only assume is a bug. I've built a kitchen timer within a UserControl. It plays an optional ticking sound as it counts down and then buzzes when elapsed. However, if the ticking sound is turned off before the timer is set, the buzz sound *will not play*. It seems that a Windows 8 app needs to play a sound *before* being minimised in order for background audio to work. To fix this, I created a silent audio file which is 1 second in duration. This file plays whether the ticking is on or off. It's a weird hack, and I hope I can figure out a better solution, but for now its all I can think of.