# WinRT Background Audio

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, media

I am going for a most simplistic playback of background audio. I don't even want to capture media controls or anything. I just want to start the app and play audio until I explicitly close it. That is, it should play audio while hidden.

I used [this article](http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/background-audio-win8dev-winrt/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341772/how-to-play-background-music-online-in-windows-8) as reference and I followed their guidance:

```xml
<MediaElement Name="someMedia"
              AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia"
              IsLooping="True"
              Source="Assets/some.mp3"
              AutoPlay="true"/>
```

Also, I added `Background Tasks` to my `Package.appxmanifest`'s `Declarations`, checked `Audio` and set the start page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also enable `SystemMediaTransportControls` and handle two events on it and on your `MediaElement` to keep them in sync.

Check this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx

Comment: I actually need to implement the controls? Weird, but I'll try shortly! Thanks

Comment: Well, that wasn't shortly - but you were right. Thanks a lot!